# Правильно ли будет использовать условия( if, ?, switch ... ) в Laravel map функции?

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно изменить массив знаю, что  для условий используют функцию filter,
Но схема массива такого, что хочу использовать функцию map .

Используют  ли  *условии* в map функции ?

Comment: В map не получиться отфильтровать элементы, там нужно вернуть что-то иначе item будет null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько мне известно `Collection map` - это аналог `array_map`.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php

Сразу видим:

> **array_map** — Применяет callback-функцию ко всем элементам указанных
>   массивов

Т.е. если вы хотите **отфильтровать** массив, то это не получится, если хотите что-то применить к каждому элементу (изменить их), то получится и тут можно использовать `if`.

```
function func($v)
{
    if ($v == 1) {
        return 'first';
    } else {
        return 'second';
    }
}

$a = array(1, 2);

var_dump(array_map("func", $a));
```

`"func"` - можно заменить на анонимную функцию, и там также можно это все дело использовать.

---

Надо понимать что `array_map` и `array_filter` - это 2 совершенно разные функции, созданные для разных нужд.